# Custom Archive Page

Tags: php, archives, templates

I want to create a custom archive page. It will look like this:

2011

January February March April May June... (Months)

May (Current Month)

- Post 1
- Post 2
- Post 3 ...

And clicked one of months (`is_month()` page) it will be look like this  :

2011 (Selected Year)

January February March April May June... (Months)

April (Selected Month)

- Post 1
- Post 2
- Post 3 ...

I tried to solve this by using `wp_get_archives();` but it's insufficient for this situation.

Anyone got some ideas?

Thanks!

Wordpress version is 3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommend checking out the [Smart Archives Reloaded plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/smart-archives-reloaded/).  It has several formats and one of them, called "fancy", displays things very similar to what you described.